# How to display form inputs on a web page

Tags: php, html, ftp

I'm currently working on my first assignment where I have no idea how to continue in. I need to use PHP and HTML to create a form that will allow the user to enter their name as text and age as a number.

The form will call to a PHP processing page. The PHP processing page will create an HTML page for the user that will display “Hello xxxxxxx” in h1 tags. In paragraph tags, the page will display “In 10 years, you will be xx years old.”  This is what i've come up with so far :

```
<html xmlns="
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; chartset=iso-8859-1" /

</head>

<body>

 
 <?php
     // echo "<pre>";
     // print_r($_POST);
     // echo "</pre>';
 ?>
 
 <h1> Hello <strong><?php echo "$uname"; ?><strong></h1>
 
 <p> In 10 years, you will be <strong><?php echo "$unumber"; ?></strong> years old. </p>
 
 

 
</body>
</html>
```

For my PHP page.
And this for my HTML:

```
<?php

   $uname = $_POST['username'];
   $unumber = $_POST['number'];
   
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC
<html xmlns=
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; chartset=iso-8859-1" />
<title> Lesson 1 </title>
</head>

<body>
   <form action="lesson-1-process.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="userform" target="_self">
       Name: <input name="username" type="text" /><br/>
       Age: <input name="number" type="text" /><br/>
       <input name="submit" type="submit" />
   </form>
   
</body>
</html>
```

I have no idea if I am doing this right. Another thing, does anyone know an easy way to get this on to a live  website with a FTP tool?  I can buy a domain but I haven't got a clue on how to set up a website. Link or answers all help. Thank you!!

Comment: You can install LAMP or WAMP on your PC to run a local webserver, you don't need a public website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The assignments to `$uname` and `$unumber` should be in the PHP script, not the page with the form.

And you need to add 10 to the form value to get the age in 10 years.

```
<html xmlns="...">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; chartset=iso-8859-1" /
</head>
<body>

 <?php
   $uname = $_POST['username'];
   $unumber = $_POST['number'];
 ?>
 
 <h1> Hello <strong><?php echo "$uname"; ?><strong></h1>
 
 <p> In 10 years, you will be <strong><?php echo $unumber + 10; ?></strong> years old. </p>
 
</body>
</html>
```